# Telerik RadPivotGrid, HtmlChart export to PDF,PNG,Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, export

I'm using Telerik RadPivotGrid control and HtmlChart Control with my project and I need to implement export feature (PNG,PDF,Excel) for both grid control and chart control. RadPivotGrid control support excel export but PNG,PDF is not supported directly, HtmlChart control doesn’t support any export feature directly but Telerik has proposed a way of exporting to PNG and PDF using an Inkscape (http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/html-chart/exporting-radhtmlchart-to-png-and-pdf.aspx) but it’s not acceptable for our project. So I'm searching for a good alternative way to implement the export features for both of those controls. If anyone have suggestions please post your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

RadHtmLChart renders with JavaScript. So, you cannot export it like this.
Perhaps using RadChart can help, it renders on the server and provides an images via a handler.
[This thread](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/grid/convert-grid-and-chart-with-custum-lines-inside-a-grid-to-pdf.aspx) offers some ideas that you might find helpful.
You can also consider a form of reporting to generate pdfs: http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/graphoverview.html.

Comment: I must use HtmlChart because its a request by my client, i found a server side approach to get HtmlChart converted to PNG using SVG Rendering Engine. there was an issue when i convert the image it didn't show the text areas in exported output but I've embedded fonts and made it working. I'm using itextsharp to get the PDF out of the converted PNG. Now my main concern is about RadPivotGrid export PDF and also i have to implement print feature for both chart control and PivotGrid it is also not supported inbuilt.

Comment: I am not sure exporting a pivot grid is even possible, it is a really interactive control. Try asking their support.
On printing - it can hardly be built-in, since it is a browser feature, not a page feature.

Answer (score -1):

Using JavaScript, one can get the SVGstring for the HtmlChart. And then using any tool this svg string can be exported to PNG, PDF or JPG.
Getting the svgstring though JavaScript:

`function getSvgContent(sender) {
            var chartRendering;
            chartRendering = $find("<%=[Chart id Here].ClientID %>").getSVGString();
            $get("<%=[Hidden field id].ClientID %>").value = escape(chartRendering);
            __doPostBack(sender.name, "");
        }`

code behind part to save this svg to file:

```
string svgText = HttpUtility.UrlDecode([Hidden_field_id].Value, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
currentSettings.SvgFilePath = Server.MapPath("/temp.svg");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(currentSettings.SvgFilePath, svgText);
```

One approach using inkscape tool has been explained in [this forum](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/exporting-radhtmlchart-to-png-and-pdf)